# Get date field value using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

im using sharepoint date in my form ,im trying to get the date field using javascript .But I did'nt get anything.

from f12 i got this input element

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ArticleDateSection$ctl01$ArticleDateField$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDate" type="text" value="9/10/2014" maxlength="45" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ArticleDateSection_ctl01_ArticleDateField_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate" title="Article Date" class="ms-input" autopostback="0">
```

and my code

```
if (document.getElementById("<%=ArticleDateField.ClientID %>").value="") {
        alert("Please enter the Date..!!")

        document.getElementById("<%=ArticleDateField.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
}
```

can you tell me what is the issue.

is there any other method to get the date field.

Comment: You'd be better off doing this a different way. If you go about asking the user the date like this, the user won't be sure which slash is for the month, day, and year. Instead, use separate boxes for the month, day, and year, so it is easier to convert to a Javascript date for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Use as , You are missing `=`

```
 if (document.getElementById("<%=ArticleDateField.ClientID %>").value == "") {
```

Comment: Afcter changfed this also i got same issue.